# In php, what does " echo `command` " do? (with single quotes)

Tags: php, linux, exec, echo

I have spend hours on google and still can't find a php doc explain this. Can someone point me to the right link please?  Got this code from a SVN:

```
<?php
  echo `snv up`;
```

the one thing I can't understand is the ` mark... It is not a quotation mark.. it is the most left-top key on a qwerty keyboard.

It seems that this will execute "svn up" as shell command, but what's the difference from exec("snv up") then?  Anyone can point me to a credible source of explanation?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backticks are the PHP shell execution operator, and they're the same as [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec) (not [`exec`](http://php.net/exec)). From [the Execution Operators documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php):

> PHP supports one execution operator: backticks (`` ` ``). Note that these are not single-quotes! PHP will attempt to execute the contents of the backticks as a shell command; the output will be returned (i.e., it won't simply be dumped to output; it can be assigned to a variable). Use of the backtick operator is identical to `shell_exec()`.

Comment: you mean, it is like a short-hand ? if I use shell_exec(args) or just use ``args``it will give me the same response?

Comment: @KarmicDice: Yes, it's just a shorthand; `shell_exec("command")` and `\`command\`` are identical as mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Thank you for the instant answer!  It saved my day.